# Unable to redirect output of a perl script to a file

Tags: bash, perl, shell, diamond-operator

Even though the question sounds annoyingly silly, I am stuck with this. The described issue occurs on both `Ubuntu 14.04` and `CentOS 6.3`.

I am using a perl script called `netbps` as posted in the answer (by `RedGrittyBrick`): https://superuser.com/questions/356907/how-to-get-real-time-network-statistics-in-linux-with-kb-mb-bytes-format-and-for

The above script basically takes the output of tcpdump (a command whose details we don't need to know here) and represents it in a different format. Note that the script does this in streaming mode (i.e., the output is produced on the fly).

Hence, my command looks like this:

`tcpdump -i eth0 -l -e -n "src portrange 22-233333 or dst portrange 22-23333" 2>&1 | ./netbps.prl`

And the output produced on the shell/console looks like this:

```
13:52:09      47.86 Bps
13:52:20     517.54 Bps
13:52:30     222.59 Bps
13:52:41    4111.77 Bps
```

I am trying to capture this output to a file, however, I am unable to do so. I have tried the following:

1. Redirect to file:

`tcpdump -i eth0 -l -e -n "src portrange 22-233333 or dst portrange 22-23333" 2>&1 | ./netbps.prl > out.out 2>&1`

This creates an empty `out.out` file. No output appears on the shell/console.

2. Pipe and grep:

`tcpdump -i eth0 -l -e -n "src portrange 22-233333 or dst portrange 22-23333" 2>&1 | ./netbps.prl 2>&1 | grep "Bps"`

No output appears on the shell/console.

I don't know much about perl, but this seems to me like a buffering issue -- not sure though? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: tcpdump -i eth0 -l -e -n "src portrange 22-233333 or dst portrange 22-23333" 2>&1 | ./netbps.prl 2>&1 does this command output anything? i removed grep "Bps"?

Comment: @Noproblem: Yes, the expected output appears on the shell/console.

Comment: tcpdump -i eth0 -l -e -n "src portrange 22-233333 or dst portrange 22-23333" 2>&1 | ./netbps.prl >>/out.out 2>&1

Comment: Behavior is same as 1 -- Produces empty out.out file and no output on console/bash

Comment: This could be due to the output from the script being buffered Try adding `$|=1;` before the while loop in the `netbps` script. That will flush the output whenever it prints something.

Comment: Adding `$|=1` works! Now I am able to push the output to a file and even grep it on the fly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a buffering problem.  Add the line `STDOUT->autoflush(1)` to netbps and it will work.

`STDOUT` is normally line buffered, so the newline on the end of `printf` should trigger a buffer flush, but because it's redirected to a file it is buffered like any normal file. You can see this with...

```
$ perl -e 'while(1) { print "foo\n"; sleep 5; }'
```

vs

```
$ perl -e 'while(1) { print "foo\n"; sleep 5; }' > test.out
```